# Eval and function scope

Tags: javascript, scope, eval

Something seems wrong with the following code.
It declares a function with `eval`, calls it — until then, everything is fine — and, calls it again but, though a function and thus gets an error.

```
var fn = function() {
    return isTwo(2);
};
var check = function() {
    eval("var isTwo = function(value) { return value == 2 }")
    console.log(isTwo(2)); // returns true
    console.log(fn()); // returns isTwo is not defined
}
check();
```

Unwrapping the `check` function made things works, but seems wrong. Why using `eval` inside of a function should change its behavior?

```
var fn = function() {
    return isTwo(2);
};

eval("var isTwo = function(value) { return value == 2 }")
console.log(isTwo(2)); // returns true
console.log(fn()); // returns true
```

Comment: `isTwo` is not in scope in `fn`  in the first code.

Comment: Don't use `eval` to declare variables. It's bad practice, and forbidden in strict mode.

Comment: @Oriol you don't know what I'm trying to achieve, so you may point out some article in the eval is evil direction, but you may weight your words ^^ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Comment: @yvesamsellem I didn't say `eval` is evil. `eval` is dangerous, but useful if you know what you are doing. However, using it to declare variables is not allowed in strict mode. You are only able to do it because due to backwards compatibility it was impossible to kill sloppy mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `eval` acts as if you had replaced the line with the code to be evaluated. Therefore, `var isTwo = function(value) { return value == 2 }` defines a **local** variable, and it can't be accessed by your other function. The reason it works in the outer block is because it is then a **global** variable, and can be accessed by your other function.

Comment: Yep, `eval` blows my mind, so I've lose my JavaScript. Thanks ^^.